# Recover deleted documents from work item in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I deleted some attachments from a Work Item in Azure DevOps, which I can see in the History. Is there any way to recover them?

Selecting them doesn't do anything.

[Screenshot: Deleted attachments in Azure DevOps work item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTjQx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted attachments can no longer be downloaded from the history.

Please refer to this latest feature update: [Remove the ability to download a deleted attachment from work item history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/boards/sprint-201-update#remove-the-ability-to-download-a-deleted-attachment-from-work-item-history)

> We fixed a small issue where users were able to download attachments from the work item history, even after the attachment was removed from the form. Now, once the attachment is removed, it cannot be downloaded from the history, nor will the download URL be available from the REST API response.